# Is there a limit in number of keys in a Redis SET UNION operation?

Tags: caching, redis, in-memory-database, in-memory

I have a scenario where I am dumping huge amount of data from Google Big Query to Redis SET data structure to get better response time. I need SET UNION operation to be done over millions of keys. I have tested with few thousands of keys and working fine. The question is, there is any limit on number of keys can be supplied to a SUNION command at a time? Is it really SUNION Key1 Key2 Key3 ..... KeyN?
Consider I have enough system capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] over millions of keys

There's no statement in Redis' documentation about a limitation on how many keys can be provided in a single `sunion` command.

BTW, I doubt that doing such operation could be a good idea in Redis. Remember that Redis will get blocked until this operation and, and no other operation will be executed until the `sunion` ends.

My best advise will be you should do it using many `sunionstore` commands, and later get all results from many sets like if the whole sets would be pages of the result of `sunion` millions of keys.

```
sunionstore key:pages:1 key1 keyN
```

...and later you would use some iterator in your application layer to iterate over all generated pages.

Comment: Thanks @matias for the fast response. I agree with you on SUNIONSTORE and application layer iteration. I actually need only the SET cardinality. So I believe SUNIONSTORE together with SCARD will work over a large number of keys.

Comment: @TibinVPaul No problem ;) I believe this is the way to go